# Pass TextInputLayout or any UI components from Activity to DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have a registration activity and a dialog fragment. Every time I press a button from registration activity, a dialog fragment with a button shows up, web service is called when the button is pressed. What I want to do is, I want to get the `TextInputLayout` from registration activity to my dialog fragment because if there's a web service error in one of the fields I want to use `setError()` to display that error. I've tried using an `LayoutInfater` to inflate the view, i don't get any error when I run the code but I also don't see inline error in my `TextInputLayout`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register, null);
```

Is it possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** pass views from one activity/fragment to other activities/fragments!
In your case, its better to use a mechanism to pass result of API call from your dialog fragment to activity. In this case there are multiple ways; one is to use a `SharedViewModel` between your dialog and activity. Another one is to use `FragmentResult` API to pass result of the API call to activity.
You can read more about how to implement these [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)